# Return Whole Object of Distinct Value in Field Elasticsearch

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I'm trying to get all distinct Customer objects from elasticsearch via NEST and I came up with the following http request:

```
{
"size":0,
"aggs":{
   "global":{
      "nested":{
         "path":"customer"
      },
      "aggs":{
         "customers":{
            "terms":{
               "field":"customer.customerId",
               "order":{
                  "_key":"asc"
               }
            },
            "aggs":{
               "single_result":{
                  "top_hits":{
                     "size":1
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
{
"took": 47,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 10,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
    "nested#global": {
        "doc_count": 10,
        "sterms#customers": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 10,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "ABC AG",
                    "doc_count": 6,
                    "top_hits#single_result": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": 6,
                            "max_score": 1.0,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "xyz",
                                    "_type": "asset",
                                    "_id": "6rms0X8BsOGDVUIux_KS",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "customer",
                                        "offset": 0
                                    },
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "customerId": 9,
                                        "name": "ABC AG"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "XYZ AG",
                    "doc_count": 4,
                    "top_hits#single_result": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": 4,
                            "max_score": 1.0,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "xyz",
                                    "_type": "asset",
                                    "_id": "4rms0X8BsOGDVUIuxvJ4",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "customer",
                                        "offset": 0
                                    },
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "customerId": 3,
                                        "name": "XYZ AG"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to return the results I'm expecting although I'm sure there could be some optimisation. My current struggle is to get this query translated into the NEST query language in .NET. How do I create all the nested aggregation and criteria using NEST?

Is there any other way to return all distinct nested customers as a whole object containing all the data? I basically just need a customer object containing it's name and the id.

My index:

```
{
   "xyz":{
      "aliases":{
      },
      "mappings":{
         "asset":{
            "properties":{
               "assetId":{
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "customer":{
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{
                     "customerId":{
                        "type":"long"
                     },
                     "name":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "fields":{
                           "keyword":{
                              "type":"keyword"
                           }
                        },
                        "analyzer":"analyzer-whitespace"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "hostname":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "fields":{
                     "keyword":{
                        "type":"keyword"
                     }
                  },
                  "analyzer":"analyzer-whitespace"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings":{
         "index":{
            "number_of_shards":"1",
            "provided_name":"xyz",
            "creation_date":"1648487273541",
            "analysis":{
               "analyzer":{
                  "analyzer-whitespace":{
                     "filter":"lowercase",
                     "type":"custom",
                     "tokenizer":"whitespace"
                  },
                  "analyzer-name":{
                     "filter":"lowercase",
                     "type":"custom",
                     "tokenizer":"keyword"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas":"1",
            "uuid":"1234556777",
            "version":{
               "created":"6020499"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you also share sample document and expected document?

Comment: @Amit I've added the example output from my request above. It would match the expected document more or less but I need the query in NEST.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the conversion from the query to NEST:

```
    searchRequest.From(0).Size(10)
        .Aggregations(ags => ags
            .Nested("customer", n => n
                .Path(p => p.Customer)
                .Aggregations(aa => aa
                    .Terms("customers", t => t
                        .Field(f => f.Customer.CustomerId)
                        .Order(o => o.KeyAscending())
                        .Aggregations(ag => ag
                            .TopHits("single_result", th => th.Size(1)))
                    )
                )
            ));
```